# MikTeX trouble with bibtex inside the standard Docker environment

Tags: bibtex, miktex

I experience weird `bibtex` behaviour, I think it does not run properly.

Symptoms:

```
No file main.aux.
No file main.bbl.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'key' on page 1 undefined on input line 17.
```

Consider this [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) from an accepted answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite{key}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

How to reproduce:

- install [MikTex Docker environment](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-docker);
- run the environment against the above file;
- above error appears.

UPD "installing biber" means, manual installation of the package! Neither [MPM](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417134/mpmcli-fatal-error-on-installing-biber-in-miktex) nor apt-get help here.

Comment: The document needs biber not bibtex.

Comment: thank you - I have update the post to another MWEB with same error condition.

Comment: The document still needs biber and not bibtex. So did you try to run `biber file`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I am not sure which call sequence is right; just calling biber did not help. See here:
A-01 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417007/working-combination-of-a-reference-system-environment-and-an-example-document-fo

Comment: @UlrikeFischer https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417134/mpmcli-fatal-error-on-installing-biber-in-miktex