# mpmcli fatal error on installing biber in miktex

Tags: miktex, biber

Following the [official mpm documentation](https://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html), I try to install the package `biber`.

[Call:](https://github.com/1605200517/tex-mwe-citing/blob/install-biber/miktex-mweb/compile-in-docker.sh)

```
mpm --admin --verify
mpm --admin --verbose --update
mpm --admin --verbose --install biber
```

[Result](https://github.com/1605200517/tex-mwe-citing/blob/install-biber/miktex-mwaeb/exec.log):

```
2018-02-25 07:53:46,327Z INFO  mpmcli - starting: mpmcli 2.9.6405 (MiKTeX 2.9.6530)
2018-02-25 07:53:46,327Z INFO  mpmcli - Operating on the shared (system-wide) MiKTeX setup
2018-02-25 07:53:46,338Z FATAL mpmcli - MiKTeX encountered an internal error.
2018-02-25 07:53:46,339Z FATAL mpmcli - Info: 
2018-02-25 07:53:46,339Z FATAL mpmcli - Source: Libraries/MiKTeX/PackageManager/PackageManager.cpp 
2018-02-25 07:53:46,339Z FATAL mpmcli - Line: 656
```

Is this a bug or do I need to change something to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no `biber` package in the MiKTeX distribution. There are two binary packages for Windows (`miktex-biber-bin`, `miktex-biber-bin-x64`).

If you need the Biber executable for macOS and/or Linux, you can try it here:

https://ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/biber/binaries